# What is Repository Pattern ? When & How to use it in enterprise applications, specially Java?

Tags: design-patterns

What is repository pattern and how it is different from DAO Pattern ? Can they be used together ?

Comment: Google will give you hundreds of links.

Comment: How does it differs from DAO ?

Answer (score 0):

In terms of what is the Repository pattern, start [here](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) but also consider how DDD [considers](https://www.infoq.com/minibooks/domain-driven-design-quickly) Repositories too. Be warned though, there's a lot of water under this pattern's bridge and it's not difficult to find lots of opposing opinions on its usage and value.

In terms of how it differs to a DAO, this is a difficult question to answer as the ultimate definition of a DAO, IMHO, is hard to pin down. At the most abstract, you could argue that a Repository *is* a DAO.

I suppose to find the answer to your question, you need to find a definition of DAO that you're happy with and then contrast with Fowler's and Evans' Repository definitions.